# not able to use conditional statement within listview onTap

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview, flutter-list-tile

I have a problem regarding if statement in dart, I want the user to tap the list tile and go to a new screen  if that list tile contains doctor then it will go to doctor screen if selected list contains patient it will go to patient screen. below is the code but thats not working as expected

this is my json file:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "p1",
        "name": "abacvj ",
        "role": "nurse",
        "phone_number":"8975412369",
        "email_id":"abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "DescriAHDLIAW JDHALOW EDWALIED EDOLJncxdlkv  ption 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/85/59/09/855909df65727e5c7ba5e11a8c45849a.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "p2",
        "name": " sjdbws",
        "role": "nurse",
        "phone_number": "8975412369",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/99/24/3a/99243a96152578f9f945c3d3041f8330.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "p3",
        "name": "jbdlaks",
        "role": "nurse",
        "phone_number": "8975412369",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/24/f4/6e/24f46ed3a8a94a7d9492e6b32892b94a.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "p1",
        "name": "Item 1",
        "role": "nurse",
        "phone_number": "8975412369",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2f/f8/4b/2ff84b77ba07ba8d5775dabf20cfaddc.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "p2",
        "name": "Item 2",
        "role": "nurse",
        "phone_number": "8975412369",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/99/24/3a/99243a96152578f9f945c3d3041f8330.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "p3",
        "name": "Item 3",
        "role": "nurse",
        "phone_number": "8975412369",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a2/27/63/a22763d7536e8489602e182200fae27a.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "p1",
        "name": "Item 1",
        "role": "nurse",
        "phone_number": "8975412369",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2f/f8/4b/2ff84b77ba07ba8d5775dabf20cfaddc.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "p2",
        "name": "Item 2",
        "role": "Patient",
        "phone_number": "8975412369",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/99/24/3a/99243a96152578f9f945c3d3041f8330.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "p3",
        "name": "Item 3",
        "role": "nurse",
        "phone_number": "8975412369",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/24/f4/6e/24f46ed3a8a94a7d9492e6b32892b94a.jpg"
    },{
        "id": "p1",
        "name": "Item 1",
        "role": "Doctor",
        "phone_number": "8975412369",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/85/59/09/855909df65727e5c7ba5e11a8c45849a.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "p2",
        "name": "Item 2",
        "role": "Doctor",
        "phone_number": "8975412369",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "Description edwey88e e92    i   2    g8ujeiehfhndlfaod 1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/24/f4/6e/24f46ed3a8a94a7d9492e6b32892b94a.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "p3",
        "name": "Item 3",
        "role": "Doctor",
        "phone_number": "8975412369",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "description": "Description fhsldkfeo;sdp keso;frsif ehf;oesfk hfeof1",
        "imageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a2/27/63/a22763d7536e8489602e182200fae27a.jpg"
    }
]
```

}

and this is main file:

```
 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List _items = [];

  // Fetch content from the json file
  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/sample.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    setState(() {
      _items = data["items"];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Call the readJson method when the app starts
    readJson();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text(
          'Ask Help',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        //change width and height on your need width = 200 and height = 50
                        minimumSize: Size(160, 50),
                      ),
                      child: const Text('Patient'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    OutlinedButton(
                      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                          side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                          minimumSize: Size(160, 50)),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text(
                        "NGO",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            // Display the data loaded from sample.json
            Container(
              child: _items.isNotEmpty
                  ? Expanded(
                      child: ListView.separated(
                        itemCount: _items.length,
                        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                            Divider(height: 1),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                ListTile(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    print(_items[index]["role"]);
                                    if (_items.contains(
                                        _items[index]["role"] == 'nurse')) {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (ctxt) => DetailPage()),
                                      );
                                    } else if (_items.contains(
                                        _items[index]["role"] == 'Doctor')) {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (ctxt) => nurse()));
                                    }
                                  },
                                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                                    child: Image.network(
                                        _items[index]["imageUrl"]),
                                  ),
                                  title: Text(_items[index]["name"]),
                                  subtitle: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(_items[index]["phone_number"],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 13.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                      Text(_items[index]["email_id"],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 13.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                              Text(_items[index]["role"],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 13.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  trailing: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                const Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Needs Help for',
                                    style:
                                        TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                const Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child:
                                      Text('Bluh bluh aaaaaaah I need help!'),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    const Text(
                                      'View Attachment',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    const Spacer(),
                                    IconButton(
                                      icon:
                                          const Icon(Icons.play_arrow_outlined),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) =>
                                                    DetailPage()));
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container(),
            ),

            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: 70,
                child: Center(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DetailPage()));
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      //change width and height on your need width = 200 and height = 50
                      minimumSize: Size(300, 50),
                    ),
                    child: const Text('Register'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `GestureDetector` use `onTap` of `ListTile`
2. Wrap your `Expanded` with a `Column` widget

Here's the modified code

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: _items.isNotEmpty
            ? Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      itemCount: _items.length,
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                          Divider(height: 1),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              ListTile(
                                onTap: () {
                                  print(_items[index]["role"]);
                                  if (_items[index]["role"] == 'nurse') {
                                     Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => DetailPage()),
                                     );
                                  } else if (_items[index]["role"] ==
                                      'Doctor') {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (ctxt) => nurse()));
                                  }
                                },
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                   child:
                                      Image.network(_items[index]["imageUrl"]),
                                ),
                                title: Text(_items[index]["name"]),
                                subtitle: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(_items[index]["phone_number"],
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 13.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                    Text(_items[index]["email_id"],
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 13.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                    Text(_items[index]["role"],
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 13.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                trailing: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              const Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Needs Help for',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              const Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Text('Bluh bluh aaaaaaah I need help!'),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  const Text(
                                    'View Attachment',
                                    style:
                                        TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  const Spacer(),
                                  IconButton(
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow_outlined),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => Form(
                                            child: DetailPage(),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            : Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I have edited the code a bit. Copy once more if you have any issues.

Comment: not navigate to new screen

Comment: I commented out the navigator.push earlier to test.

Comment: i remove the comment still not working

Comment: I edited my new code please check

Comment: any runtime errors? are you getting the print statement from onTap?

Comment: no runtime error. i am getting the print statement correct output from onTap